# P-adic numbers and quotients

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory

I'm currently reading the [Elliptic Curves Number Theory and Cryptography](https://people.cs.nycu.edu.tw/%7Erjchen/ECC2012S/Elliptic%20Curves%20Number%20Theory%20And%20Cryptography%202n.pdf).

There is a proof on page 164. As far as I understand, it uses p-adic notation. I'm not very confident with the p-adics yet, so I've been confused by this proof for a while.

First, they introduced this rule:

$$
\frac{a}{b + O(p^k)} = \frac{a}{b} + O(p^k),\text{when}\ v_p(b) = 0, v_p(a) \ge 0, k > 0
$$

Then in the proof they derived the coordinates of the point on elliptic curve:

$$
x = \frac{m_1^2}{p^2} + O(p^{-1}) \\ y = -\frac{m_1^3}{p^3} + O(p^{-2})
$$

which I kind of understood.

And then they did this:

[image]

Since there's no explanation I tried to derive this result by myself:

$$
\frac{x}{y} = \frac{\frac{m_1^2}{p^2} + O(p^{-1})}{-\frac{m_1^3}{p^3} + O(p^{-2}} = \frac{m_1^2 * p + O(p^2)}{-m_1^3 + O(p)} = 
$$

$$
\frac{m_1^2 * p + O(p^2)}{-m_1^3} + O(p) = O(p)
$$

I can't understand where's my mistake in reasoning, since I used the rule above properly:

$$
v_p(m_1^3 * p + O(p^2)) = 1 \ge 0, v_p(-m_1^3) = 0, k = 1 \gt 0
$$

Comment: That’s not a mistake, but they’re computing $p^{-1}x/y$, so you would get $O(1)$, which is consistent with the given answer.

Comment: Won't I get $\frac{m_1^2 + O(p)}{-m1^3} + O(1) = -\frac{1}{m_1} + O(1) + O(p)$ which has $O(1)$ in it? It won't disappear $\pmod{p}$

Comment: Note that the result that you get is still correct. It’s just imprecise. What you should do is divide by $p$ first and then apply the rule to $\frac{\ast}{m_1^3+O(p)}$.